# Can't reach Bugzilla on localhost

Tags: apache, bugzilla

I'm trying to set up Bugzilla to run on a Windows machine on my network.  I've used Apache as the web server (via ApacheHaus) and am using Strawberry Perl.

So far, I can start the web server, and when I navigate to `localhost`, I arrive at a default page that comes with the ApacheHaus installation.

When I run `checksetup.pl` I get a list of optional perl modules I haven't installed, a warning that I haven't set the `max_allowed_packet` parameter in MySQL, and then I'm told

> Now that you have installed Bugzilla, you should visit the 'Parameters' page (linked in the footer of the Administrator account) to ensure it is set up as you wish - this includes setting the 'urlbase' option to the correct URL
>
> checksetup.pl complete

If I understand correctly, I should be able to navigate to `localhost/bugzilla` and get the Bugzilla landing page.  But I get "Webpage is not available."  My first guess is that my `urlbase` option is not specified correctly.  I can't find anywhere to change this other than in `C:/bugzilla/data/params.json` and when I set it to `localhost/bugzilla` there, I get an Internal Server Error.

Any hints on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed bugzilla on ubuntu. Follow this link[Bugzilla installation on ubuntu](https://rallycommunity.rallydev.com/answers?id=kA014000000PK23CAG). I'm sure this will help you. Also Once installed correctly, point your urlbase to **/localhost/bugzilla/**

Note : Intially even after bugzilla was installed I had to enter localhost/bugzilla/index.cgi as my url for my bugzilla home page to load. Later after installing a patching pointing to localhost/bugzilla/ loads the home page. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.

To solve it, you should have to give correct path for 
"Perl execution file" in index.cgi and all cgi files at Bugzilla folder.

So, you should have to change first line on every cgi file.Its default have,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
```

Instead of this you have to give correct path, In my case I change path as this,

```
#!/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl -T
```

use text editor like notepad++ to change every cgi files path. Hope this will help !